# PyQt5 - how to enable a new (third) button that fail to show after running clicked pushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

Here is a simple program to create 2 pushbuttons and a third pushbutton when either of the first two buttons is clicked.  But it doesn't work.  When I click one of the first two buttons I get the message in the console indicating it has been clicked but no 3rd button appears.  Why??  Thanks!

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 class Ui_Form(object):
     def setupUi(self, Form):
         Form.setObjectName("Form")
         Form.resize(400, 300)
     def setup_pushButton(self, word, x, y, width, height):
         self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x, y, width, height))
         self.pushButton.setText(word)
         self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.but_clicked)
     def create_pushButtons(self):
         self.setup_pushButton('apple', 100, 110, 75, 23)
         self.setup_pushButton('car', 20, 110, 75, 23)
     def but_clicked(self):
         print('clicked')
         self.setup_pushButton('house', 250, 110, 75, 23)
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     ui = Ui_Form()
     ui.setupUi(Form)
     ui.create_pushButtons()
     Form.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As you can see in my solution you have to create all three buttons first. Then hide one and show on command when clicked. The hide/show function can be swapped using an functional if-statement under which the start condition  is car= 0 & apple = 1 and switches when either button is clicked resulting in: car= 1 &  apple = 0. Please select the answer if it is the preferred solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below code with inline commenting will help you figure out what went wrong and why I put things where they are. Most important... your button names may change every now and then therefor I've made the code variable for you by using `setattr` and `getattr`. Less work to do afterwards and more pythonic  with an eye on OOP ;-)

> **Note:** Normally initialization of buttons occur in the `setupUI` by convention. In your case we treat the buttons as additions to the main `setupUI` not taken into account earlier because its an additional feature in a fictional product asked by your beloved product launching customer.

Enjoy!

Tributton example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget, object):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        print '> This is start of main app'

        super(Ui_Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUI(self)

        self.buttonlist = [('apple', 100, 110, 75, 23),
                       ('car', 20, 110, 75, 23),
                       ('house', 250, 110, 75, 23)]

        self.create_pushButtons()

        print '> Everything is painted... lets show it on screen.'

    def setupUI(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Twobutton Example", "Twobutton Example"))

    def create_pushButtons(self):

        for item in self.buttonlist:

            # set attribute with variable name (e.g. "car" may change into "cars")
            setattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (item[0]), QtWidgets.QPushButton(self))

            # painting the variale named button.
            #                                          x,       y,   width,  height
            getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (item[0])).setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4]))
            getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (item[0])).setText(item[0])

            # create the connection aswell for the variable named button in a single "go".
            if item[0] in [self.buttonlist[0][0], self.buttonlist[1][0]]:
                getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (item[0])).clicked.connect(self.buton_clicked)

            if item[0] == self.buttonlist[2][0]:

                getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (item[0])).clicked.connect(self.house_but_clicked)
                getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (item[0])).hide()

    def buton_clicked(self):

        #"Murder she wrote".. : who done it... was it car or apple... where did the order came from?
        sender = self.sender()
        text = sender.text()

        print('The button %s was clicked' % text)
        # print 'clicked' to python standard out. In an editor like komodo edit you see imidiatly what you do.
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # car button:
        # if button house is hidden... lets show it (again).
        if text in [self.buttonlist[1][0], ]:
            getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (self.buttonlist[2][0])).show()

        # apple button:
        # if button house is show... lets hide it again.
        if text in [self.buttonlist[0][0], ]:
            getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % (self.buttonlist[2][0])).hide()

    def house_but_clicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()

        print('The button %s was clicked and its going to be connected to something else' % sender.text())
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.show()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> **EDIT :** to show inccorect use of variable objectname after comment OP on december 10th.

**OP script**:

```
snippet...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    t = ui
    ui.create_pushButtons()

    Form.show()
#    print dir(__builtins__)
#    l = dir(Ui_Form.setup_pushButton)
#    from pprint import pprint
#    pprint(l)
#    t = Ui_Form()
    variables = [i for i in dir(t) if not inspect.ismethod(i)]
    print variables
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output print variables:

> ['**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**doc**', '**format**', '**getattribute**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**module**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', 'but_clicked', 'create_pushButtons', 'pushButton1', 'setupUi', 'setup_pushButton']

**Tributton example script**:

```
snippet...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    t = ui
    ui.show()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    variables = [i for i in dir(t) if not inspect.ismethod(i)]
    print variables
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output print variables:

> This is start of main app
>   Everything is painted... lets show it on screen.
>   ['DrawChildren', 'DrawWindowBackground', 'IgnoreMask', 'PaintDeviceMetric',
>   ...
>   'pos', 'previousInFocusChain', 'property', 'pushButton_apple', 'pushButton_car', 'pushButton_house', 'pyqtConfigure', 'raise_', 'receivers', 'rect', 'releaseKeyboard',
>   ...
>   'windowOpacity', 'windowRole', 'windowState', 'windowTitle', 'windowTitleChanged', 'windowType', 'x', 'y']

As you can see there are three separate atributes with their own objectName space, namely ...**'pushButton_apple'**, **'pushButton_car'** and **'pushButton_house'**.

Comment: Actually, I since found a way to do what I want to do.  The third button was being created it just didn't show.  By adding the line

Comment: in your code all buttons use the  same `objectName` space (variable) which is an intrinsically incorrect way of writing your script! Each button should have its own variable `objectName` space such that one can refer to it and modify its behavior or looks..

Answer (score -1):

Actually, my code did produce the new button it just wasn't showing.  By adding --self.pushButton.show() -- it now works fine. Here's the complete revised code that works.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
     def setupUi(self, Form):
          Form.setObjectName("Form")
          Form.resize(400, 300)
     def setup_pushButton(self, word, x, y, width, height):
          self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x, y, width, height))
         self.pushButton.setText(word)
     self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.but_clicked)
 def create_pushButtons(self):
     self.setup_pushButton('apple', 100, 110, 75, 23)
     self.setup_pushButton('car', 20, 110, 75, 23)
 def but_clicked(self):
     print('clicked')
     self.setup_pushButton('house', 250, 110, 75, 23)
     self.pushButton.show()
 if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
      ui = Ui_Form()
      ui.setupUi(Form)
      ui.create_pushButtons()
      Form.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```